# Creating large amount of Views in Code

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I'm trying to create a custom View that contains a list of `CheckBoxes` based on my database. This means I have to create the Views at run-time, and can't do it in XML. However, the method I'm using for this is very slow. Is there a faster method to create large amount of Views in code?

For example, with the 18 types in my database, it can take over 1 second to create all the `CheckBoxes`.

```
class FilterView : LinearLayout {

private fun init(types : List<Type>){

    ... setup

    // Creating the CheckBoxes, this takes all the time. 
    checkboxes = Array(types.size, {

        AppCompatCheckBox(context).apply {
            text = types[it].type
            CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(this, ColorStateList(states, intArrayOf(colours[it], colours[it])))
        }
    })

   ... add to view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is a Recyclerview. It can all be explained [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html). The downvote was likely because this is assumed to be common knowledge or easily googled on your own. I was new once too. Here you go.

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer is super rude. Ignoring the fact a simple glance at my profile would show that I'm aware of `RecyclerView`, you didn't answer the question in a helpful manner. Simply linking to documentation isn't very useful. On another note, I have considered `RecylerView` for this, but I was looking for a different solution, one that would allow me access to the Views better.

Comment: No one was being rude. You yourself asked why the downvote, I was telling you the most likely reason. The link provided explains why a Recyclerview is efficient and its benefits giving you information, thus allowing you to move forward & enabling an informed decision as to how to handle this problem. If you see the last part of the answer where is said "I was once new too" it implies I sympathize with you on the downvote.